# How can we travel to Canada with our maid?

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, luxury, visa-sponsors

We have a Canadian PR and would like to travel to Canada next month for a three-month holiday. During this time we would like to take with us our maid who works in Dubai with us and is on our sponsorship. She is an Indian national like us.

How we can arrange a tourist visa for our maid?
What are the documents required for her to travel with us?

Comment: Do you have an established travel history of taking her with you, and her having a genuine holiday on those trips?  Because I suspect the border officers will be minded to assume that she's coming to act as a maid, at least for some of the time, and that would likely constitute working unlawfully.

Comment: So what's the solution, means I need to apply regular visit visa for her?

Comment: I'm no expert on Canadian procedures; hopefully someone who is will be coming along shortly to help.  If this were a visit to the UK, you could apply for a *Domestic Workers in a Private Household* visa for her, but it would require you to [pay her at the UK national minimum wage](https://www.gov.uk/domestic-workers-in-a-private-household-visa/eligibility), and the visas aren't cheap.

Comment: Note that for applicants from the UAE, current processing times for Canadian visitor visas are 36 days, plus the time required to give biometrics (which are required for Indian citizens on visitor visas.)  It may not be possible to obtain a visa in time if the trip is "next month" (December 2019.)

Comment: Thanks, please do let know the process to obtain visit visa for Canada

Comment: Are you genuinely Canadian PR, meaning Permanent Residents? What do you mean by "visiting Canada"? Are you not living there?

Comment: Given the visa issues, it may be simpler, and better for the maid, to use the money for her airfare etc. to send her somewhere she wants to go and can easily travel for her vacation. Perhaps she has family she would like to visit in India.

Comment: It reads here like this is an unusual setup, but what about all the people travelling with nannies, maids, butlers, drivers, private teachers and the likes? I am sure there has to be some standardised way to handle this?

Comment: @skymningen The point is ‘travelling’ - temporary visitors. The OP appears to have permanent residency in Canada, which puts a different slant on the situation.

Comment: @Traveller But the maid has no permanent residency as far as I can see from the post? It is her work permission which is making this difficult, not her employers, right?

Comment: Many countries try to encourage local hiring for jobs like maid.

Comment: @DJClayworth Canada is very lax on enforcing PR residency requirements, so tens of thousands of people have Canadian permanent residency without actually living there

Answer (score 13):

**There are going to be problems here**

[Immigration Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/work-without-permit/business.html#toc09) says that:

> People employed in a personal capacity, for example, as a domestic servant, personal assistant or nanny (caregiver), on a full-time basis by short-term temporary residents generally meet the business visitor criteria in paragraphs R187(3)(a) and (b) and may enter as business visitors.

This means that in general someone can apply to bring a personal domestic worker with them to Canada while they are visiting, provided they work for them full time. You would need to apply for a Visitor Visa in the business category for your maid. That doesn't mean it will be approved. You would need to explain why you needed to bring a maid with you from Dubai, rather than hire one in Canada. Short term maids are easy to hire in Canada.

**However there is a significant problem.**

The problem is that you are not short-term temporary residents of Canada. You are, according to your question, Permanent Residents (PR). (Since you say you are living in Dubai and only visiting Canada it's possible that this is a mistake in the question, in which case I recommend you edit it, and the problem will then go away.)

As permanent residents of Canada you could, according to the government website, only bring your maid with you if you got her a work visa. Since you can stay in Canada indefinitely, the presumption is that your maid would also stay in Canada. You might also have to explain why you are only "visiting" Canada and residing elsewhere. However I am not a lawyer, and I am not sure of the exact definition of "short-term resident", and you might want to consult a lawyer as to whether there is some way that you can accomplish this. Giving up your permanent resident status might be one way to go.

Comment: I don't know if Canada cares about this, but don't most countries not like for people to get permanent resident status and then not actually live in the country? I would be concerned that if OP shows up at the border, and as part of explaining all this, says something along the lines of "I live in Dubai but I have this PR card so I should be allowed in," they could argue that he abandoned his residence?

Comment: @aidanh010 Canada is very lax about enforcing residency requirements for its PR holders, at least for now

Answer (score 3):

A Canadian visit visa costs C$100. Information about eligibility and how to apply is available here https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html Processing times for applications submitted from the UAE are currently 36 days, excluding the time needed to give biometrics https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html

As has been pointed out in comments, bringing a maid on a visit visa and having her work while in Canada would be illegal. Given the circumstances, it may be hard to craft a credible visit visa application that would convince Canadian Immigration that there is no intention to work.

Comment: Bringing a maid on a tourist visa and have her work as a maid would be illegal.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree - will amend my answer. The OP indicated in an answer to a (now-deleted) comment that the maid working while in Canada was not the intention, altho IMHO it would likely be hard to convince Canadian immigration of that.

Comment: I'm actually revising my view. Apparrently the correct visa for a domestic servant accompanying their employer is a visitor visa.